# Método copy do Numpy não cria uma deep copy?

Tags: python, numpy

Eu estou dando uma olhada nos arrays do Numpy e vi que o método `copy` deveria fazer um *deep copy* do array. Quando eu crio um array de strings ou de valores numéricos isso parece ser verdade. Entretanto, quando eu crio um array contendo uma instância de uma classe que eu criei, o método `copy` copia apenas a referência (*shallow copy*). Por exemplo:

```
import numpy as np

class Teste:
   def __init(self, var1, var2):
      self.var1 = var1
      self.var2 = var2

   def __copy__(self):
      return Teste(self.var1, self.var2)

t = Teste(20, 30)

arr1 = np.array([t])
arr2 = arr1.copy()

id(arr1[0) == id(arr2[0]) == id(t)
```

A comparação na última linha de código retorna `True`, o que indica que tanto `arr1` quanto `arr2` guardam a mesma referência para o objeto `t`. A minha expectativa era que o método `copy` criasse um novo objeto `Teste`.

Eu consigo esse comportamento quando eu uso o método `deepcopy` do módulo `copy`. Sendo assim, eu queria saber se eu estou usando o método `copy` do array corretamente e se esse é realmente o comportamento esperado desse método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comportamento esperado é esse mesmo.

A [documentação](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy) cita que `ndarray.copy` é [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56028647) a `numpy.copy`, e a [documentação de `numpy.copy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) diz o seguinte:

> *np.copy is a **shallow copy** and will not copy object elements within arrays*

A mesma documentação recomenda que se use `copy.deepcopy` caso você queira que os objetos também sejam copiados. E nesse caso, nem precisa do método `__copy__`:

```
import numpy as np

class Teste:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

t = Teste(20, 30)

arr1 = np.array([t])
arr2 = arr1.copy()

# imprimindo o id antes (são todos iguais)
print(id(t))
print(id(arr1[0]))
print(id(arr2[0]), arr2[0].var1, arr2[0].var2)

# usando deepcopy
from copy import deepcopy
arr2 = deepcopy(arr1)
# o id depois mudou, mas o conteúdo dos campos foi copiado
print(id(arr2[0]), arr2[0].var1, arr2[0].var2)
```

Vale lembrar que você só deve criar os métodos `__copy__` e `__deepcopy__` se quiser que sua classe use uma implementação específica para criar as cópias, caso contrário não é nem necessário criá-los. Da [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> *In order for a class to define **its own copy implementation**, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`*

Mas no seu caso não me parece necessário, já que você quer copiar exatamente todos os campos, sem nenhuma lógica adicional.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu estou seguindo o livro do Deitel, Python for Programmers, e na seção 7.12 ele diz que o método ndarray.copy faz uma deep copy do array. Pelo visto o autor deu um baita vacilo. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado.